# OpenCL clEnqueueNDRangeKernel in loop

Tags: opencl

I am developing a simple radix-2 FFT algorithm using using opencl 1.2 on Mac. I am trying to use the HD 5000 graphics in my laptop

my host code is like this:

```
gws=4;
lws=1;

for (cur_iter=0; cur_iter <= 2; cur_iter++){
    ret = clSetKernelArg(r2kernel, 3, sizeof(cl_int), (void *)&cur_iter);
     printf("iter %d \n", cur_iter);
    ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, r2kernel, 1, NULL, &gws, &lws, 0, NULL, &kernelDone);
    // printf("ret %d \n", ret);
    ret = clWaitForEvents(1, &kernelDone);
    // printf("ret %d \n", ret);
}
```

cur_iter means the current stage of FFT. My kernel code is like this:

```
kernel void radix2(global float2 * x, global float2 * w,int iter, int cur_iter)
{

int gid = get_global_id(0); // number of threads

int butterflySize = 1 << (iter-cur_iter-1);
int butterflyGrpDist = 1 << (iter-cur_iter);
int butterflyGrpBase = (gid >> (iter-cur_iter-1))*(butterflyGrpDist);
int butterflyGrpOffset = gid & (butterflySize-1);

int a = butterflyGrpBase + butterflyGrpOffset;
int b = a + butterflySize;

 printf("gid %d pass %d, %d, %d ,total iter %d \n", gid,cur_iter,a,b,iter);


float2 u0 = x[a];

float2 u1 = x[b];

float2 tmp;

 DFT2(u0,u1,tmp);

int waddr=butterflyGrpOffset<<cur_iter;

float2 twiddle = w[waddr];

MUL(u1,twiddle,tmp);



x[a] = u0;

x[b] = u1;

}
```

I printed out the gid and cur_iter in kernel. I expect to get 4 kernels (for 8 point FFT) at each iteration. But what I get is like this

```
iter 0 
gid 0 pass 0, 0, 4 ,total iter 3 
gid 1 pass 0, 1, 5 ,total iter 3 
gid 2 pass 0, 2, 6 ,total iter 3 
gid 3 pass 0, 3, 7 ,total iter 3 
iter 1 
gid 0 pass 0, 0, 4 ,total iter 3 
gid 1 pass 0, 1, 5 ,total iter 3 
gid 2 pass 0, 2, 6 ,total iter 3 
gid 3 pass 0, 3, 7 ,total iter 3 
gid 0 pass 0, 0, 4 ,total iter 3 
gid 1 pass 0, 1, 5 ,total iter 3 
gid 2 pass 0, 2, 6 ,total iter 3 
gid 3 pass 0, 3, 7 ,total iter 3 
gid 0 pass 1, 0, 2 ,total iter 3 
gid 1 pass 1, 1, 3 ,total iter 3 
gid 2 pass 1, 4, 6 ,total iter 3 
gid 3 pass 1, 5, 7 ,total iter 3 
iter 2 
gid 0 pass 0, 0, 4 ,total iter 3 
gid 1 pass 0, 1, 5 ,total iter 3 
gid 2 pass 0, 2, 6 ,total iter 3 
gid 3 pass 0, 3, 7 ,total iter 3 
gid 0 pass 0, 0, 4 ,total iter 3 
gid 1 pass 0, 1, 5 ,total iter 3 
gid 2 pass 0, 2, 6 ,total iter 3 
gid 3 pass 0, 3, 7 ,total iter 3 
gid 0 pass 1, 0, 2 ,total iter 3 
gid 1 pass 1, 1, 3 ,total iter 3 
gid 2 pass 1, 4, 6 ,total iter 3 
gid 3 pass 1, 5, 7 ,total iter 3 
gid 0 pass 0, 0, 4 ,total iter 3 
gid 1 pass 0, 1, 5 ,total iter 3 
gid 2 pass 0, 2, 6 ,total iter 3 
gid 3 pass 0, 3, 7 ,total iter 3 
gid 0 pass 1, 0, 2 ,total iter 3 
gid 1 pass 1, 1, 3 ,total iter 3 
gid 2 pass 1, 4, 6 ,total iter 3 
gid 3 pass 1, 5, 7 ,total iter 3 
gid 0 pass 2, 0, 1 ,total iter 3 
gid 2 pass 2, 4, 5 ,total iter 3 
gid 3 pass 2, 6, 7 ,total iter 3 
gid 1 pass 2, 2, 3 ,total iter 3
```

Which means at each iteration, the cur_iter being passed to my kernel always start from zero and the instances of kernel initiated is also wrong, even its value is 2 or 3 . I want to know why. Any kind of help will be appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the *printf* buffer is getting re-output for each iteration (each iteration contains the entirety of what's been printed before, plus more. There's no way that you'd get the same gid multiple times in a pass. If you use clFinish instead of clWaitForEvents does it change anything?

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. My problem is solved. I compare the FFT results with Matlab and they match. I think I am not supposed to use the print function in my kernel. But this brings up another question : is there anyway we can monitor the variable in kernel ?  FYI, both clFinish and clWaitForEvents work